# How to assign a product source from Event Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, multi-source-inventory

When a product is saved, I want to check if the product has an inventory source set, and if not, set one. The event name I'm observing is `catalog_product_save_after`.

This is the Observer code:

```
class validateProductSources implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var Http
     */
    protected $request;
    protected $productRepoInterface;
    protected $sourceItemsBySku;

    protected $_sourceItemsSaveInterface;
    protected $_sourceItemFactory;


    public function __construct(
        Http $request,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepoInterface,
        GetSourceItemsBySkuInterface $sourceItemsBySku,
        SourceItemsSaveInterface $sourceItemsSaveInterface,
        SourceItemInterfaceFactory $sourceItemFactory
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->productRepoInterface = $productRepoInterface;
        $this->sourceItemsBySku = $sourceItemsBySku;
        $this->_sourceItemsSaveInterface = $sourceItemsSaveInterface;
        $this->_sourceItemFactory = $sourceItemFactory;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->request->getParams();
        $productId = $this->request->getParam('id');
        $product = $this->productRepoInterface->getById($productId);
        $sku = $product->getSku();
        $sourceItems = $this->sourceItemsBySku->execute($sku);
        if(!$sourceItems){
            $sourceItem = $this->_sourceItemFactory->create();
            $sourceItem->setSourceCode('default');
            $sourceItem->setSku($sku);
            $sourceItem->setQuantity(1);
            $sourceItem->setStatus(1);
            $this->_sourceItemsSaveInterface->execute([$sourceItem]);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is executed. I know this because I've tested it with the logger. The products source is not set though.

What baffles me is that if I use the same code in a controller (minus the request to get the product ID), the source is successfully set.

Could anyone tell me Why this happens, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by changing `catalog_product_save_after` to `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after` in events.xml, and using the following code:

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getData('product');
        $sku = $product->getSku();
        $sourceItems = $this->sourceItemsBySku->execute($sku);
        if(!$sourceItems){
            $sourceItem = $this->_sourceItemFactory->create();
            $sourceItem->setSourceCode('default');
            $sourceItem->setSku($sku);
            $sourceItem->setQuantity(1);
            $sourceItem->setStatus(1);
            $this->_sourceItemsSaveInterface->execute([$sourceItem]);
        }
    }
```